# Hide labels for features without data

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a FeatureLayer that uses a ClassBreaksRenderer. The renderer loads data from a collection like so:

```
var renderer = new esri.ClassBreaksRenderer(
            null,
            function (graphic) {
                return data[graphic.attributes.ID];
            });
```

Using a LabelLayer, is there a way to only render labels when the feature has a value (as determined by the ClassBreaksRenderer)?

I am able to "hide" the labels in this instance, by setting the font size to 0, but the DOM elements are still created. On a layer with thousands of features where only a sub-set are displayed, that kills performance.